# My Select List Binding Not Work Properly in Edit Portion

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am Getting List Of Service Order And Initially   Service Status Is Open Now As Admin I am Responsible For Status Update I have Done Some Thing Like That Using Java Script Service status Is enum List
[image]

My Actual View Code Is Like Below

```
<form asp-action="EditServiceStatus" asp-controller="Electronics" asp-route-id="@servieOrder.ServicesInquiryID" asp-route-ServiceStatus="@servieOrder.Servicesstatus"  method="post">
  <span id="confirmEdit_@servieOrder.ServicesInquiryID" style="display:none">
     <span>
      <select asp-for="@servieOrder.Servicesstatus" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Servicesstatus>()">
        <option value="">Select Status</option>
      </select>
    </span>
 <input Class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Yes"/>
   <span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirmEdit('@servieOrder.ServicesInquiryID', false)">No</span>
   </span>
 </form>
 <span id="mainSpan_@servieOrder.ServicesInquiryID">
    @servieOrder.status
</span>
```

Now After Submitting This Form How To Get Changed Value From  Drop Down To Controller Action Method
My Controller Action Method Like That

```
[HttpPost]
  public async  Task<IActionResult> EditServiceStatus(int Servicesstatus, int Id)
    {
    try
        {
        }
     }
```

I try To Change Services Status Using This Way I want To get Changed Value From Dropdown To Action Method
The Drop Down Select List get Open ,Close, IN Progress And Reject Status

Answer (score 1):

You could pass id by `asp-route-id` because the id is unchanged.But the status is changed,so you could not pass like this way,just change the name of the selectlist and match it with the backend:

```
<select asp-for="@servieOrder.Servicesstatus" name="Servicesstatus" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Servicesstatus>()">
```

Here is the whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class ServiceOrder
{
    public int ServicesInquiryID { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public Servicesstatus Servicesstatus { get; set; }
}
public enum Servicesstatus
{
    Yes=1,
    No=2
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ServiceOrder>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServicesInquiryID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Servicesstatus)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var servieOrder in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => servieOrder.ServicesInquiryID)
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-action="EditServiceStatus" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@servieOrder.ServicesInquiryID" method="post">
                    <span id="confirmEdit" >
                        <span>
                            <select asp-for="@servieOrder.Servicesstatus" name="Servicesstatus" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Servicesstatus>()">
                                <option value="">Select Status</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                        <input Class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Yes" />
                        <span class="btn btn-primary">No</span>
                    </span>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = new List<ServiceOrder>()
    {
        new ServiceOrder(){ServicesInquiryID=1,Servicesstatus=Servicesstatus.Yes,status=1},
        new ServiceOrder(){ServicesInquiryID=2,Servicesstatus=Servicesstatus.No,status=2},
        new ServiceOrder(){ServicesInquiryID=3,Servicesstatus=Servicesstatus.Yes,status=1}
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public void EditServiceStatus(int Servicesstatus, int Id)
{

}
```

Result:

[image]